# Generating a list of files

Tags: python, file

I have this this code here... it generates a list of files and folders in a directory

```
import os
for x in os.listdir("C:\Users"):
    text = text + "\n" + x
f = open("List.txt", "w")
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

But how can I get it to do two things...

Firstly well read whats in the folders and keep going until there is only a child.

Secondly when it goes down a level it adds a tab. Like this

```
Level 1 (parent)
    Level 2 (child)
```

How can I get it to add that tab in? For infinite amount of levels?

Comment: I don't think `"C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\"`  compiles.

Comment: I had some other files on there but I took it off. Should work now.. it has a 0.99 probability of not working for you unless your user is `Fabian`

Comment: Use `/` as a path separator, use `r''` raw strings, or double up your backslashes: `'C:\\Users\\...'`.

Comment: To avoid confusion I changed it..

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `os.walk`?

Comment: It compiles guys... don't panic xD. And os.walk? what info does that give me?

Comment: you can try the `tree` command , `tree >List.txt` in your command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.walk()` instead:

```
start = r'C:\Users'
entries = []
for path, filenames, dirnames in os.walk(start):
    relative = os.path.relpath(path, start)
    depth = len(os.path.split(os.pathsep))
    entries.extend([('\t' * depth) + f for f in filenames])
with open("List.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write('\n'.join(entries))
```

In each loop, `path` is the full path to the directory the filenames and dirnames are directly contained in. By using `os.path.relpath` we extract the 'local' path, count the depth and use that for the number of tabs to prepend each filename with.